# Rename open-zeppelin tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

My name is Martín and I created the tag [open-zeppelin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-zeppelin) a few years ago. I did it because I work at [OpenZeppelin](https://openzeppelin.com/), the team behind [OpenZeppelin Contracts](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts), a widely used smart contract library.

Unfortunately, I made a mistake since that's not the right way to write it, but without the hyphen: `openzeppelin`. For reference [this is the same tag in Ethereum Stack Exchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/tags/openzeppelin/info).

For accuracy and consistency, I'd like to ask the tag to be renamed and its description copied from Ethereum Stack Exchange.

Thanks!

Comment: Should `[open-zeppelin]` maybe be made a synonym of `[openzeppelin]`, so that this mistake will not happen again in the future?

Comment: @Lino Only problem is that `[openzeppelin]` currently doesn't exist...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I wasn't entirely clear, make `[open-zeppelin]` a synonym *after* `[openzeppelin]` has been created

Comment: @Lino nah, the system is smart enough to tell you not to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Done and done. I even had to use my mod powers to annotate the tag wiki creation ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67334693/revisions) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67334694/revisions)) as the description contains first-person language that could cause confusion for readers looking at the revision history. Thanks for letting us know.